# kubernetes pod cannot resolve local hostnames but can resolve external ones like google.com

Tags: kubernetes, kvm, coredns

I am trying kubernetes and seem to have hit bit of a hurdle. The problem is that from within my pod I can't curl local hostnames such as **wrkr1** or **wrkr2** (machine hostnames on my network) but can successfully resolve hostnames such as google.com or stackoverflow.com.

My cluster is a basic setup with one master and 2 worker nodes.

**What works from within the pod:**

- curl to **google.com** from pod -- works
- curl to another service(kubernetes) from pod -- works
- curl to another machine on same LAN via its IP address such as 192.168.x.x -- works
- curl to another machine on same LAN via its hostname such as wrkr1 -- does not work

**What works from the node hosting pod:**

- curl to google.com --works
- curl to another machine on same LAN via
  its IP address such as 192.168.x.x -- works
- curl to another machine
  on same LAN via its hostname such as wrkr1 -- works.

> Note: the pod cidr is completely different from the IP range used in
> LAN

the node contains a hosts file with entry corresponding to wrkr1's IP address (although I've checked node is able to resolve hostname without it also but I read somewhere that a pod inherits its nodes DNS resolution so I've kept the entry)

Kubernetes Version: **1.19.14**

Ubuntu Version: **18.04 LTS**

Need help as to whether this is normal behavior and what can be done if I want pod to be able to resolve hostnames on local LAN as well?

Comment: If you do a `k get pods -n kube-system`, in the output is there coredns and / or nodelocaldns Pods? Also check this guide https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/ as dnsutils can help you

Comment: @AndD yep there are 2 coredns pods in ready and running state

Comment: have you tried adding the same dns server configured in your node hosting pod. in coredns /etc/resolv.conf
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#coredns-configmap-options
forward: Any queries that are not within the cluster domain of Kubernetes will be forwarded to predefined resolvers (/etc/resolv.conf).

Comment: @AmjadHussainSyed can you please elaborate how to change this config file for core dns?

Comment: you need to update the corefile which is the coredns config file which will be there in the configmap. you can configure the config file and change the following to your appropriate ip forward . 10.150.0.1 either you can point to a resolv.conf file or you can also add ip of the dns server which has the answers.
you read more bout this here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#coredns-configmap-options

Comment: @AmjadHussainSyed well i changed it to refer to the symlink /run/resolve/resolve.conf but it still has no impact

Comment: did u restart the pod?

Comment: @AmjadHussainSyed well i didnt restarted the pod i restarted the deployment

Comment: How/where are virtual machines deployed?

Comment: @moonkotte on a server via kvm

Comment: @JayD what is the output you get when you run this?
kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup your-dns-name

Comment: @AmjadHussainSyed well i tried it like kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup wrkr1.local
and i got server cant find wrkr1.local NXDomain

Comment: @JayD is the node /etc/hosts the only place where wkrk1 ip address is present? Are there any local network DNS server that can resolve those requests to IPs?

Comment: @moonkotte well yes i have no special dedicated dns server setup i just use avahi -daemon for name resolution because without that even my nodes cant resolve each other via hostnames. the router does dns resolution

Comment: @JayD by the way, how is your cluster set up? On premise using `kubeadm`?

Comment: @moonkotte yep on premise with one server acting as master and two VMs spawned on a separate server acting as worker nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What happens

> Need help as to whether this is normal behavior

This is normal behaviour, because there's no DNS server in your network where virtual machines are hosted and kubernetes has its own DNS server inside the cluster, it simply doesn't know about what happens on your host, especially in `/etc/hosts` because pods simply don't have access to this file.

> I read somewhere that a pod inherits its nodes DNS resolution so I've
> kept the entry

This is a point where tricky thing happens. [There are four available](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy) `DNS policies` which are applied per pod. We will take a look at two of them which are usually used:

- "**Default**": The Pod inherits the name resolution configuration from the node that the pods run on. See related discussion for more details.
- "**ClusterFirst**": Any DNS query that does not match the configured cluster domain suffix, such as "www.kubernetes.io", is forwarded to the upstream nameserver inherited from the node. Cluster administrators may have extra stub-domain and upstream DNS servers configured

The trickiest ever part is this (from the same link above):

> Note: "Default" is not the default DNS policy. If dnsPolicy is not
> explicitly specified, then "ClusterFirst" is used.

That means that all pods that do not have `DNS policy` set will be run with `ClusterFirst` and they won't be able to see `/etc/resolv.conf` on the host. I tried changing this to `Default` and indeed, it can resolve everything host can, however internal resolving stops working, so it's not an option.

For example `coredns` deployment is run with `Default` dnsPolicy which allows `coredns` to resolve hosts.

### How this can be resolved

**1. Add `local` domain to `coreDNS`**

This will require to add `A` records per host. Here's a part from edited coredns configmap:

This should be within `.:53 {` block

```
file /etc/coredns/local.record local
```

This part is right after block above ends (SOA information was taken from the example, it doesn't make any difference here):

```
local.record: |
  local.            IN      SOA     sns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. 2015082541 7200 3600 1209600 3600
  wrkr1.            IN      A      172.10.10.10
  wrkr2.            IN      A      172.11.11.11
```

Then `coreDNS` deployment should be added to include this file:

```
$ kubectl edit deploy coredns -n kube-system
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          items:
          - key: Corefile
            path: Corefile
          - key: local.record # 1st line to add
            path: local.record # 2nd line to add
          name: coredns
```

And restart `coreDNS` deployment:

```
$ kubectl rollout restart deploy coredns -n kube-system
```

Just in case check if `coredns` pods are `running and ready`:

```
$ kubectl get pods -A | grep coredns
kube-system   coredns-6ddbbfd76-mk2wv              1/1     Running            0                4h46m
kube-system   coredns-6ddbbfd76-ngrmq              1/1     Running            0                4h46m
```

If everything's done correctly, now newly created pods will be able to resolve hosts by their names. [Please find an example in coredns documentation](https://coredns.io/2017/05/08/custom-dns-entries-for-kubernetes/)

**2. Set up DNS server in the network**

While `avahi` looks similar to DNS server, it does not act like a DNS server. It's not possible to setup `requests forwarding` from `coredns` to `avahi`, while it's possible to proper DNS server in the network and this way have everything will be resolved.

**3. Deploy `avahi` to kubernetes cluster**

There's a ready image with `avahi` [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/flungo/avahi). If it's deployed into the cluster with `dnsPolicy` set to `ClusterFirstWithHostNet` and most importantly `hostNetwork: true` it will be able to use host adapter to discover all available hosts within the network.

### Useful links:

- [Pods DNS policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy)
- [Custom DNS entries for kubernetes](https://coredns.io/2017/05/08/custom-dns-entries-for-kubernetes/)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and came up with this solution:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns-custom
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  lan.server: |
    lan:53 {
      errors
      cache 30
      forward . 192.168.2.1
    }
```

`192.168.2.1` is my local DNS (in my case my router) and `lan` is my hostname.